# GPS Location on Button Press

Tags: java, android, android-activity, gps, location

I am currently writing an app which will access the current location on the press of a button, and print it out. What I have right now is a method which gets the last known location. I have seen in many places that one is to implement a class that gets the location. My current code returns it as a string, but it only gets the location that was last updated by the phone. How can I change this so that when I press the button and call a method that uses this String, it will get the currentLocation rather than the lastLocation?
Thank you so much!
Also, This is my first ever android app, and I only have intermediate knowledge of Java and class implementation.

```
public String getLocation(){
    String userLocation;

    try {
        LocationManager locMgr = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location recentLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        String userLocator = recentLoc.toString();
        userLocation = compressString(userLocator);
        //userLocation = recentLoc.toString();

    }
            catch(Exception e) {
        userLocation = "Location failed";
    }

    return userLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your GPS is turned off right now. If you turn on your device's location services, it will print out the last location which is near by you. If it won't work, you must implement LocationListener class to your activity. Like at [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener=new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat=location.getLatitude();
        double lng=location.getLongitude();

    }
};
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);//or LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this in onClick method

```
private void _getLocation() {
// Get the location manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {}
public void onProviderEnabled(String p) {}
public void onProviderDisabled(String p) {}
public void onStatusChanged(String p, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };
    locationManager
            .requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, loc_listener);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    try {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        lat = -1.0;
        lon = -1.0;
    }
}
```